# Borland/Embarcadero convert DFM form to MS Visual studio form

Tags: windows, gratis, visual-studio, delphi

I have been handed a Borland C++Builder v5 project and told to convert it so MS Visual studio 2105. Is there any tool which can help me? It doesn’t have to do it all, just “as much as possible” to ease my load.

To make things simpler, the project uses no 3rd party VCL components, just the bog standard text box, combo box, etc. The project is reasonably structured, in the code for the form, OnClick() is generally simple and calls functions in other, purse code, .CPP files.

In the absence of an answer, I will create a new, blank form in MSVC, add fields like those of the old project one by one and copy past the implementation into them.

Before I do that, does anyone one know of a gratis for commercial use Windows application which will convert .DFM files into whatever the equivalent is for MSVC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://delphi.icm.edu.pl/ftp/tools/dfm2api120.zip .you can download this tool. there are later versions but i am not able to find it.